# C# ASP.NET - Using a handler for Requests

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a Handler for AJAX. So the idea is that my JQuery sends a `$.get` request to the Handler but I am having some trouble capturing the request.

```
var example = Request.QueryString["getParam"].ToString();
```

Returns:

> The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context

Is there a specific way I can capture the Request in a Handler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var example = context.Request.QueryString["getParam"].ToString();
```

Comment: It's usually good to add a bit more explanation to the post than just a one line code dump. Such as saying that `context` comes from the arguments of the `IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest` method.

Comment: Sorry @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I went home and forgot to mark it! All done now :)